# Install cURL in CentOS

Tags: php, apache, curl

Can someone direct me on how to install cURL on a CentOS server. Preferably through WHM if it's possible to recompile PHP that way.. I am a noob in SSH and this is a production server.

Comment: I read somewhere you can do this in Easy Apache.. anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can change it from easy apache. you can even upgrade your php version there.

Comment: awesome, I did it through SSH though.. after switching to root (su) I ran "/scripts/easyapache", thanks Adam!